# _Layout loading twice even though I changed _ViewStart to null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My single page application using Angular and ui-router, .NET MVC is loading the layout twice. Once in Index.cshtml and once in the ui-view page Index.cshtml contains. I don't understand why its doing this especially when I changed _ViewStart to null. The only line that is responsible for generating the _layout now is within

Index.cshtml

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: make sure that in your controller your calling return PartialView() and not return View() also you can add @{
  Layout = null;
} to the top of the partial view your controller is returning

Comment: Interestingly enough, after trying both of those solutions - separately and together - the shadow layout still appears

Comment: I have had this very same issue...post the view and the controller that returns it...we'er just overlooking something simple...

Comment: Turns out my Angular catch all routes.MapRoute method in the RouteConfig file was incorrect. It was mapping all urls and returning the index view. Therefore my index rendered first correctly, then within the ui-vew div, it rendered once more

Comment: Awesome...Glad you figured it out. That exact thing has frustrated me for hours before.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you're returning PartialView() for dynamically loaded razor views. Also make sure that you're not specifying a Layout for your partial views.